# BigQuery Jobs insert without any predefined schema

Tags: google-bigquery

Is is possible to define the `jobSpec` variable without any schema fields information ?

So for exemple here is the kind of joSpec I have usually :

```
       var jobSpec = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: ClientAccount,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        allowJaggedRows: true,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
        schema: {
          fields: [                                                             
         {name: 'Column1', type: 'STRING' },
         {name: 'Column2', type: 'STRING' },
         {name: 'Column3', type: 'STRING' }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

I would like to have something like this :

```
       var jobSpec = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: ClientAccount,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        allowJaggedRows: true,
        writeDisposition: 'WRITE_APPEND',
        schema: fields.whateverisinmytable  // dream property I want 
      }
    }
  };
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
autodetect: true
```

you should use [configuration.load.autodetect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.autodetect) property

> > **configuration.load.autodetect**    - boolean   - *Indicates if we should automatically infer the options and schema for CSV and JSON sources.*